# Expected number of transfers/move in a 6 round dice game

Tags: probability, expected-value, dice

In a dice game, the game piece moves the number of steps that the dice show, except when it shows 4, then 1 step is moved instead. calculate the expected number of transfers after 6 rounds.

Is the correct answer (1 + 2 + 3 + 1 + 5 + 6)/6 = 3

Comment: What is a transfer? Also, if the minimum step is 1, how could the game piece only move 3 places after 6 rounds?

Comment: You do not need to divide by 6.